# How to get balanceOf of tron smart contract

Tags: solidity, tron, tronlink

I am using tronlink chrome extension and trying to call balanceOf method of a smart contract. I am very new to smart contract. Unable to find any solution. Please check my code:

```
let contractDetail = await window.tronWeb.trx.getContract('TG7DLMkJPYeG4QTZ8Qfgk9Mu7ePM5SQpbN');
            let contract = await window.tronWeb.contract(contractDetail.abi.entrys, 'TG7DLMkJPYeG4QTZ8Qfgk9Mu7ePM5SQpbN');
            balance = contract.balanceOf.call('TNkJRejobNuZhV2LiwfGQ7wPNiLtcbDueS');
            console.log(balance)


//Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with tronlink and have no way to check the code, so I'm not going to post it as answer. But it seems like the line should be `contract.balanceOf('<address>');` since balanceOf() is usually a function on Ethereum tokens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `tronWeb.trx.getBalance(CONTRACT_ADDRESS);`

Your code should look like

```
balance = await tronWeb.trx.getBalance('TNkJRejobNuZhV2LiwfGQ7wPNiLtcbDueS');
```

Comment: This will return TRX balance of address. Not the token balance of smart contract, presumably TRC20.

Answer (score 2):

balanceOf requires one argument.

```
'balanceOf(address)'
```

Instead of

```
contract.balanceOf.call('TNkJRejobNuZhV2LiwfGQ7wPNiLtcbDueS');
```

You should pass in the address into `balanceOf`

```
contract.balanceOf('TNkJRejobNuZhV2LiwfGQ7wPNiLtcbDueS').call();
```